# How do I get PHP5 to display errors on Nginx server?

Tags: php, debugging, nginx

My client is running an Nginx server with PHP5. When a PHP page encounters an error, it is halting operation and not displaying anything to the screen. How can I see errors on the screen, while I work on the site?

Here are some of the relevant settings in PHP.ini:

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL

; html_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: On

; log_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide settings:

```
display_errors = on
display_startup_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your nginx config, inside your php block

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```